# Evaluating $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{2^{8\cos(h)}}{8h}\left [ \sin^{8}(\pi/6+h))-\sin^{8}(\pi/6) \right ]$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{2^{8\cos(h)}}{8h}\left [ \sin^{8}(\pi/6+h))-\sin^{8}(\pi/6) \right ]$$

*My Attempt:*

For $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin^{8}(\pi/6+h)-\sin^{8}(\pi/6)}{h}=f'(x)=8\cdot \sin^{7}(\pi/6) \cdot \cos(\pi/6)$
so now total equation can be written as  $2^8\cdot2^{-7}\cdot(1/2)$.

What step did I do wrong here? (I got the wrong answer.)

Comment: Where did $\cos \pi/6$ go?

Comment: You get $2^8 \cdot \frac{1}{2^7} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ because of the $\cos(\pi / 6)$

Comment: i'm sorry i edited it

Comment: I suppose that $2^{8cosh}$ stands for $2^{8\cos(h)}$. If this is the case, please edit.

Comment: I think the answer is $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: yes thank u guys ..i noticed my mistake

Comment: Wait a sec, why is it $2^8$?

Comment: in $2^(8cosh)$ , cosh =1 as h tends to 0

Comment: but the limit is "$\frac{2^8}{0}$". I used with quotation marks because obviously it's invalid.

Comment: no i used the h in denominator for writing $f'(x)$

Comment: Oh I understand. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{2^{8\cos(h)}}{8h}(\sin^{8}(\pi/6+h)-\sin^{8}(\pi/6))$

$=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{2^{8\cos(h)}}{8}\cdot\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin^{8}(\pi/6+h)-\sin^{8}(\pi/6)}{h}$

$=\frac{2^8}{8}\frac{d}{dx}\sin^8(x)|_{x=\frac{\pi}{6}}$

$=\frac{2^8}{8}\:8\sin^7(\frac{\pi}{6})\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})$

$=2^8(\frac{1}{2})^7(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$

$=\sqrt{3}$